# Mutt doesn't ask to purge deleted emails

Tags: email, mutt

I am using mutt to read emails from 2 accounts Gmail and Yahoo. I notice that if I mark, for example, 3 of my yahoo emails for deletion, and then press, say <kbd>F2</kbd>, to switch to Gmail, Mutt will ask me whether I want to purge those 3 messages before syncing the yahoo account; it will not switch to gmail until the next <kbd>F2</kbd> press though.

However, Mutt will not ask the same question if I mark some Gmail emails to delete and switch to yahoo; it automatically expunges the marked-to-be-deleted messages. If I press the dollar symbol $ or quit Mutt, it will still ask to purge messages.

Why is the difference?

Comment: Hi @roaima. Yes I am using IMAP for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of asking for purging is the default. It should only not occur if you have `set delete=yes` somewhere. However, the fact that this only happens for one of the two accounts suggests that you are using two different configs.